# Not able to add certificate policy extension using openssl APIs in c++

Tags: c++, openssl

I tried using following syntax for the same :

- `add_ext(x509OutCertificate, NID_certificate_policies, "Policy: 2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.54 ,CPS: https://www.verisign.com/cps");`
- `add_ext(x509OutCertificate, NID_certificate_policies, "2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.54,https://www.verisign.com/cps");`

& many more combinations.

but not able to add this extension in certificate. Any clue what is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you add more code, please?

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment, but the comment does not have the space.

```
$ grep -R NID_certificate_policies *crypto/objects/obj_dat.h:   NID_certificate_policies,3,&(lvalues[512]),0},
crypto/objects/objects.h:#define NID_certificate_policies   89
crypto/objects/obj_mac.h:#define NID_certificate_policies       89
crypto/x509v3/v3_cpols.c:NID_certificate_policies, 0,ASN1_ITEM_ref(CERTIFICATEPOLICIES),
crypto/x509v3/pcy_cache.c:  ext_cpols = X509_get_ext_d2i(x, NID_certificate_policies, &i, NULL);
crypto/x509v3/v3_purp.c:        NID_certificate_policies, /* 89 */
```

Looking at `v3_cpols.c`, there's an ominous warning:

```
/* Certificate policies extension support: this one is a bit complex... */
```

Here's how its declared:

```
const X509V3_EXT_METHOD v3_cpols = {
  NID_certificate_policies, 0,ASN1_ITEM_ref(CERTIFICATEPOLICIES),
  0,0,0,0,
  0,0,
  0,0,
  (X509V3_EXT_I2R)i2r_certpol,
  (X509V3_EXT_R2I)r2i_certpol,
  NULL
};

ASN1_ITEM_TEMPLATE(CERTIFICATEPOLICIES) = 
    ASN1_EX_TEMPLATE_TYPE(ASN1_TFLG_SEQUENCE_OF, 0, CERTIFICATEPOLICIES, POLICYINFO)
ASN1_ITEM_TEMPLATE_END(CERTIFICATEPOLICIES)

IMPLEMENT_ASN1_FUNCTIONS(CERTIFICATEPOLICIES)
```

`v3_cpol` is then used in `ext_dat.h`:

```
static const X509V3_EXT_METHOD *standard_exts[] = {
  &v3_nscert,
  &v3_ns_ia5_list[0],
  &v3_ns_ia5_list[1],
  &v3_ns_ia5_list[2],
  &v3_ns_ia5_list[3],
  &v3_ns_ia5_list[4],
  &v3_ns_ia5_list[5],
  &v3_ns_ia5_list[6],
  ...
  &v3_cpols,
  ...
};
```

There does not appear to be documentation or clear usage. The two books I have on OpenSSL lack a treatment on it. It looks like you are in muddy waters.

Perhaps the folks at the [OpenSSL user's list](http://www.openssl.org/support/community.html) can help out. I suggest it because some folks on the list can probably answer it (SH, DT, VD, etc), but I have not seen them on Stack Overflow's site.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a long time for this question, but i looked into openssl1.0.2k source code, and i found its not support add cps extension directly:

```html
static STACK_OF(POLICYINFO) *r2i_certpol(X509V3_EXT_METHOD *method,
                                         X509V3_CTX *ctx, char *value)
{
    WriteLogToFile("In r2i_certpol");
    STACK_OF(POLICYINFO) *pols = NULL;
    char *pstr;
    POLICYINFO *pol;
    ASN1_OBJECT *pobj;
    STACK_OF(CONF_VALUE) *vals;
    CONF_VALUE *cnf;
    int i, ia5org;
    pols = sk_POLICYINFO_new_null();
    if (pols == NULL) {
        X509V3err(X509V3_F_R2I_CERTPOL, ERR_R_MALLOC_FAILURE);
        return NULL;
    }
    WriteLogToFile("Before X509V3_parse_list");
    vals = X509V3_parse_list(value);
    WriteLogToFile("After X509V3_parse_list");
    if (vals == NULL) {
        X509V3err(X509V3_F_R2I_CERTPOL, ERR_R_X509V3_LIB);
        goto err;
    }
    ia5org = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sk_CONF_VALUE_num(vals); i++) {
        cnf = sk_CONF_VALUE_value(vals, i);
        if (cnf->value || !cnf->name) {
            char str[1000];
            sprintf(str, "cnf->value: %s, cnf->name: %s", cnf->value, cnf->name);
            WriteLogToFile(str);
            X509V3err(X509V3_F_R2I_CERTPOL,
                      X509V3_R_INVALID_POLICY_IDENTIFIER);
            X509V3_conf_err(cnf);
            goto err;
        }
        pstr = cnf->name;
        WriteLogToFile(pstr);
        if (!strcmp(pstr, "ia5org")) {
            ia5org = 1;
            continue;
        } else if (*pstr == '@') {
            STACK_OF(CONF_VALUE) *polsect;
            polsect = X509V3_get_section(ctx, pstr + 1);
            if (!polsect) {
                X509V3err(X509V3_F_R2I_CERTPOL, X509V3_R_INVALID_SECTION);

                X509V3_conf_err(cnf);
                goto err;
            }
            pol = policy_section(ctx, polsect, ia5org);
            X509V3_section_free(ctx, polsect);
            if (!pol)
                goto err;
        } else {
            if (!(pobj = OBJ_txt2obj(cnf->name, 0))) {
                X509V3err(X509V3_F_R2I_CERTPOL,
                          X509V3_R_INVALID_OBJECT_IDENTIFIER);
                X509V3_conf_err(cnf);
                goto err;
            }
            pol = POLICYINFO_new();
            if (pol == NULL) {
                X509V3err(X509V3_F_R2I_CERTPOL, ERR_R_MALLOC_FAILURE);
                goto err;
            }
            pol->policyid = pobj;
        }
        if (!sk_POLICYINFO_push(pols, pol)) {
            POLICYINFO_free(pol);
            X509V3err(X509V3_F_R2I_CERTPOL, ERR_R_MALLOC_FAILURE);
            goto err;
        }
    }
    sk_CONF_VALUE_pop_free(vals, X509V3_conf_free);
    return pols;
 err:
    sk_CONF_VALUE_pop_free(vals, X509V3_conf_free);
    sk_POLICYINFO_pop_free(pols, POLICYINFO_free);
    return NULL;
}
```

The "CPS" has to be in section part, which is configured by openssl.conf file, so anyone met this problem has to put cps in that configure file, and tell openssl to search that part, like the code below:

```html
bool AddX509ExtensionFromFile(X509* cert, X509* issuer, int nid, char* value,char* extFile)
{
    if (extFile)
    {
        long errorline = -1;
        X509V3_CTX ctx2;
        CONF* extconf = NCONF_new(NULL);
        if (!NCONF_load(extconf, extFile, &errorline))
        {
            if (errorline <= 0)
            {
                printf("NCONF_load error\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("error on line %ld of config file '%s'\n", errorline, extFile);
            }
        }

        char* extsect = "default";

        X509V3_set_ctx_test(&ctx2);
        X509V3_set_nconf(&ctx2, extconf);
        if (!X509V3_EXT_add_nconf(extconf, &ctx2, extsect, NULL))
        {
            printf("error loading extension section %s\n", extsect);
        }

        X509V3_set_ctx(&ctx2, issuer, cert, NULL, NULL, 0);
        X509_EXTENSION* ex = X509V3_EXT_conf_nid(NULL, &ctx2, nid, value);
        if (!ex) {
            return false;
        }

        int result = X509_add_ext(cert, ex, -1);

        X509_EXTENSION_free(ex);

        return (result == 0) ? true : false;
    }
    return false;
}
```